# Python Tkinter error - can't invoke "bind" command

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to bind a button to a simple function.
This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def printName(event):
    print 'hi my name is Beni'

button_1.bind("<Button-1>",printName)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The error I get is:

```
TclError: can't invoke "bind" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be _all_ your code since you've never defined `button_1`...  We can generally be most helpful to you if you can create a simple runnable snippet where we can copy/paste and see the error ourselves.

Comment: Ho hell,  I am breaking my own stupidity records... Thank you!

Comment: btw: `Button( ..., command=function_name )`

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `button_1`.

For example:

```
button_1 = Button(root, text="ButtonName")
```

So your entire code snippet would be:

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()

def printName(event):
    print('hi my name is Beni')

button_1 = Button(root, text="ButtonName")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>",printName)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```